# Retornar todos checkboxes desmarcados via jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

Preciso identificar todos checkboxes DESMARCADOS para adicionar uma classe por jquery neles, mas sempre que submito o formulário com 1 ou 2 checkbox selecionado, todos outros checkboxes desmarcados acabam selecionados.

```js
    //Valido meu form
    $('#enviar').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      //verifico se tem algum checkbox marcado e retorna o ID
      if($(".stck:checked").length > 0){
        var arr = [];
        $(".stck").prop("checked", true).each(function(item){
            arr.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });
        console.log(arr);
        return arr;
      } 
      
      //Se não, pego o ID dos desmarcados
      else { 
        var arr = [];
        $(".stck").prop("checked", false).each(function(item){
            arr.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });
        console.log(arr);
        return arr;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="stck" name="sticker" id="A" value="A"  />
    <input type="checkbox" class="stck" name="sticker" id="B" value="B"  />
    <input type="checkbox" class="stck" name="sticker" id="C" value="C"  />
    <button id="enviar">enviar</button>
```

```
//---MEU JS
```

Queria poder identificar os checkboxes não selecionados para injetar uma classe neles.

Comment: Qual é o código onde estás a tentar adicionar a classe?

Comment: Você tá marcando todos os outros checkbox quando executa `$(".stck").prop("checked", true)` dentro do `if`. Por isso ele tá marcando todas as caixas quando você seleciona uma ou mais opções. Dê uma olhada no código que postei abaixo, acredito que vá resolver o seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, a solução mais enxuta que cheguei foi essa:

```js
$('#enviar').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      var arr = [];
      $.each($("input[name='sticker']:checked"), function(){         
        arr.push($(this).val());
     }); 
      console.log(arr);      
      $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").addClass('NaoSelecionado');
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="stck" name="sticker" id="A" value="A"  />
    <input type="checkbox" class="stck" name="sticker" id="B" value="B"  />
    <input type="checkbox" class="stck" name="sticker" id="C" value="C"  />
    <button id="enviar">enviar</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo disponibilizado Leonardo, me ajudou muito!!

Comment: Imagina @Soundstorm; retribuia ajudando também a comunidade. Abs e bons estudos! Tamo junto

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Eu faria isso da seguinte forma:

```
$('#enviar').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    // cria o array com os id's dos checkbox selecionados
    var array_id = $("input.stck:checkbox:checked").map(function(e){

        return $(this).val();

    }).get();

    // aplica a classe desejada para os checkbox que não foram selecionados
    $("input.stck:checkbox:not(:checked)").addClass('nome_da_classe');
});
```

Obs1: alterar o `nome_da_classe` para a classe desejada.

Obs2: no seu código, para funcionar o envio de múltiplos valores selecionados você deve usar o nome do input como um array, assim: `name="sticker[]"`

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo tempo disponibilizado Alexandre, me ajudou muito!!
Suas observações foram muito importantes para me ajudar a melhorar meu código, iniciei meus estudos a pouco mais de 1 mês em Js e Jquery, ainda preciso melhorar muito.